# How to delete a tree properly in C++

Tags: c++

I build a binary tree which every right child may be the same as its sibling's left child. When I was trying to delete it, I am not sure if the whole tree is deleted completely.

```
class TreeNode
{
  public:
  int val;
  TreeNode* left;
  TreeNode* right;
  TreeNode(int v)
  {
    val = v;
    left = NULL;
    right = NULL;
  }
  ~TreeNode()
  {
    //testing if our tree is correct;
    cout<<val<<" ";
    delete left;
    delete right;
  }
};

  /*
              2
            4,  3
          3,  2,  6
        2,  9,  5,  2
      10, 5,  2,  15, 5
  */

   // 2->4   2->3    4->3  4->2   3->2 3->6
```

delete root;

So, as you can see, I print the node value when it is deleted, but my result looks like this {2 4 3 2 10 5 9 5 2 2 9 5 2 5 2 15 3 2 9 5 2 5 2 15 6 5 2 15 2 15 5}, it seems like when we are trying to delete the left child which suppose to be deleted as another node's right child, system still can visit this node and print the result out. I mean, it supposed to be NULL already, right?

Comment: `delete` doesn't set the deleted pointer to `NULL`, it seems you're having a misconception.

Comment: Please confirm. On tier 2, both 4 and 3 point to 2 on tier 3? If so you need to clean up your ownership. When it comes to delete-ers, Highlander's Law is in full effect. There can be only one.

Comment: Deleting any kind of pointer does not set it to nullptr.  If you want that, you must add a line to explicitly do so.  Deleting a nullptr is allowed.

Comment: Very tricky to null 3's pointer to 2 after deleting 4. Pointers have no back channel and there is no way to know who else points to the allocation that was just deleted. You may find `std::shared_ptr` helpful here.

Comment: The data structure that you describe is not a tree. In a tree, a node can have exactly one parent.

Answer (score 0):

Given

> every right child may be the same as its sibling's left child.

`delete`ing the left and right child in the destructor of the class is bound to create problems. No matter which of the siblings you `delete` first, the other sibling will be left with a dangling pointer. Calling `delete` on that leads to undefined behavior.

> I mean, it supposed to be NULL already, right?

That is not right. Even if that were right for a pointer, there is no way to make sure that all the pointers that point to the object are set to NULL. Simple example:

```
int* p1 = new int;
int* p2 = p1;
delete p1;    // How does the run time know to also set p2 to NULL.
```

---

You need to use a different strategy for deleting all the nodes of the tree.

1. Change the destructor to be an atomic delete operation. i.e.

   ```
   ~TreeNode() {}
   ```
2. Write a function to gather all the nodes in a `std::set<TreeNode*>` given a starting node.
3. Call `delete` on each of the objects in the gathered `std::set<TreeNode*>`.

Comment: Might be worth adding that the `set` is used to prevent duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

> I build a binary tree which every right child may be the same as its sibling's left child.

Although similar to a tree, such graph is technically not a tree. I'm not familiar with established name for such structure, so I'll call it a pyramid.

> I mean, it supposed to be NULL already, right?

Deleting an object through a pointer doesn't make other pointers pointing to that object null.

The problem is that you attempt to delete the shared children twice.

Given that the nodes don't have unique ownership of their children, it is not correct to delete them in the destructor. So you should remove `delete left; delete right;` from the destructor.

You can use the following algorithm to delete all children. The idea is to delete rooot and all children directly to the left while leaving all right children of those subpyramids unthouched. All those untouched right children are still left children of the right subpyramid. Then repeat with the right child as the root. An example:

```
void deletePyramid(TreeNode* node) {
    TreeNode* right;
    do {
        right = node->right;
        while(node) {
            TreeNode* left = node->left;
            delete node;
            node = left;
        }
    } while(node = right);
}
```

As you may notice, this algorithm is non-recursive and has constant spatial complexity. Essentially, the algorithm pretends that the structure is like this:

```
          2
         / \
        4,  3
       /   / \
      3,  2,  6
     /   /   / \
    2,  9,  5,  2
```